# Возврат значения асинхронной функции TypeScript

Tags: typescript, async-await, асинхронность, typescript-типы

Как сделать, чтобы асинхронная функция, построенная через async/await вернула значение в TypeScript?

```
const func = async (param: type) : object {}
```

Не работает, а писать все в одной функции не очень.
Нужно чтобы асинхронная функция вернула именно значение. То есть return object допустим. И чтобы потом через await в другой функции можно было использовать функцию func как значение.

И если даже заменить на Promise, оно не работает, то есть нельзя потом написать

```
async function getCompany(companyName: string) {
      const companyInfo = await getCompanyIdByName(companyName);
}
```

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

[image: введите сюда описание изображения]

Comment: Эээ, что? Сформулируйте внятней что нужно

Comment: Переформулировал, надеюсь стало понятнее.

Comment: тип возвращаемый `async` функцией **всегда** - `Promise`.

Comment: при этом, при использовании `await` - получается конкретное значение.

Comment: И как в таком случае обрабатывать значение? Через .then?

Comment: @RIXIN, через `await` же

Comment: Так-с. Сейчас скрины прикреплю в чем проблема.

Comment: @Grundy, вот, правил

Comment: Перечитай мои сообщения и рекомендацию в ошибке :) _тип возвращаемый async функцией **всегда - Promise**_, а ты указываешь `object`

Comment: У тебя тип неправильный, редактор же подсказывает мол "Мб ты хотел вернуть Promise<object>?

Comment: @Алексей, даже если я ставлю Promise<object> оно не работает.

Comment: Ну ещё неплохо бы из функции возвращать то что вы *обещали* вернуть. Сейчас она не возвращает ничего.

Comment: @AlexeyTen, так там же return body... Или это не то?

Comment: @RIXIN,  это не то.

Comment: @Grundy, тогда не очень понимаю как именно должно быть

Comment: ты должен вернуть `Promise`. Сейчас у тебя из функции - ничего не возвращается, что равносильно `Promise<void>`, а ты хочешь `Promise<object>`

Comment: А. Всё понял, спасибо.

Comment: ну и текущая функция `request` - судя по всему, не возвращает `Promise`

Comment: А. Я всё исправил. Всем спасибо